# what's the meaning of this sentence? "don’t let that color how you think of them"

Tags: meaning, sentence

Good or bad, habits have the same origins. They result in very different experiences, of course, but **don’t let that color how you think of them.**

I can't understand the meaning of the bold part.
Thank you in advance

Comment: @tchrist -- Voting to reopen, since I couldn't find a definition of the term after a moderate amount of searching.  Unreasonable to expect a newbie to do any better.

Comment: It's a fairly common idiom, but oddly I can't find a definition on the web.

Comment: @HotLicks It's not an idiom, it's a proper and standard English usage. [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/color) seems pretty clear - definition 2c of the verb: *INFLUENCE - "The lives of most of us have been colored by politics … "*. Voting to keep it closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, *colour* means *influence*, so the text effectively reads "Don't let that influence how you think of them," i.e. "Don't think of them badly because of that."

> Colour (verb) INFLUENCE
>
> If something colours your opinion of something, it influences your opinion in a negative way:
>
> - I'm sure my views on marriage are coloured by my parents' divorce.
> - I'm trying not to let my judgment be coloured by that one incident.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/colour)

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the metaphor, it merely means that you shouldn't let the fact that habits result in very different experiences  be determinative in your thinking about habits and induce you to look at them in a particular way, induce you to think habits have a particular aspect, a particular "colour"; in other words that characteristic of habits teaches you nothing about habits, which sounds rather like a truism.